# Azure VPN Gateway with RADIUS - public IP unchanged

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-network, radius, azure-vpn

I configured Azure VPN with RADIUS authentication. All seam to work fine, at least when I connect with the client the connection is successful and the PPP adapter IP Address is changed correctly. However why the Ethernet/public IP Address is not changed?

I can ping the VM in the Azure VM, but the public IP remains the same.

Answer (score 1):

A VPN uses the PPP adapter and does not affect the Ethernet/Wireless adapter. This is the expected behavior.

Comment: I understood that, however I believe this is specific to Azure VPN because there are plenty of client VPN that once installed will change the IP address of the Ethernet/Wireless.